# Sitecore analytics upgrade code issue Sitecore 9.3

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I am upgrading Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3. While upgrading Sitecore.analytics reference to target version 9.3, I'm getting error on below code.

**Getting Error in the below code**

Error message "does not contain a definition for AuthenticationLevel."

Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.PasswordValidated;
Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(contactIdentifier);

**Full Code here**

```
public void StartTracking(global::Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            return;

        if (!Tracker.IsActive)
        {
            Tracker.StartTracking();
        }

        IdentifyContact(user);
    }

   public Contact IdentifyContact(global::Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user)
    {
        if (user == null)
            return null;

        string contactIdentifier = GetContactIdentifier(user);

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(contactIdentifier) || contactIdentifier.Contains("anonymous") || Tracker.Current == null || Tracker.Current.Session == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.AuthenticationLevel = AuthenticationLevel.PasswordValidated;
        Tracker.Current.Session.Identify(contactIdentifier);

        return Tracker.Current.Contact;
    }
```

How can we replace AuthenticationLevel in Sitecore 9.3 analytics ?

Anyone help on this issue

Comment: What error? .....

Comment: I'm getting the error like does not contain a definition for AuthenticationLevel. It seems AuthenticationLevel won't support for sitecore 9.3 analytics

Comment: "AuthenticationLevel " is obsolete in Sitecore 9.0 onward, what code you want to update here?

Comment: want to update the code according to sitecore 9.3 analytics

Comment: if you can share your complete code here, it will be good. otherwise this link can help you - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2981/bind-current-visitor-with-sitecore-contact/2984

Comment: Maybe if you explain what the code that uses that property is trying to do and we can suggest an alternative.Without knowing the purpose of the code, its impossible to know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

In 9.x `Tracker.Current.Contact.Identifiers.AuthenticationLevel` is gone. You only have known and unknown for each identifier you assign to a contact. If you still want to know if they were password validated vs not, then I would create a custom contact facet and put that information in there.

Also, identifying a contact is now done like the code below. This allows you to have multiple identifiers on a contact. Instead of the one identifier in 8.2

```
Tracker.Current.Session.IdentifyAs("emailaddress", email.ToLower());
```